# what is the best way to delete elements at execution time of a foreach in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
let aUsers=[{"name":"goku"},{"name":"cell"},{"name":"vegeta"},{"name":"freezer"}]

aUsers.forEach((user,i)=>{
  if(user.name=="cell" || user.name=="freezer"){
    aUsers.splice(i,1); //this causes a problem..
  }
})

console.log(aUsers);
```

I know that I should use `filter`, but I don't know how to get my elements to be `removed` from the `array` at the same time my `foreach` runs.

I would know how to solve this problem, but after running the `foreach`, maybe there is a better way to do it.

how can I do it?

Comment: Because `filter` returns a new array, you can assign aUsers to the filter function. `aUsers = aUsers.filter( /.../ );`.

Comment: Ironically, your example works - by happy accident.  Perhaps you can modify the example to remove two adjacent elements, like try checking `if(user.name=="cell" || user.name=="vegeta")`, then you'll actually illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use `filter` instead of `forEach`:

```js
let aUsers=[{"name":"goku"},{"name":"cell"},{"name":"vegeta"},{"name":"freezer"}]

const newUsers = aUsers.filter(user => user.name !== "cell" && user.name !== "freezer");

console.log(newUsers);
```

If you must change the array in-place, then iterate backwards:

```js
let aUsers=[{"name":"goku"},{"name":"cell"},{"name":"vegeta"},{"name":"freezer"}]

for (let i = aUsers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (['cell', 'freezer'].includes(aUsers[i].name)) {
    aUsers.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(aUsers);
```

Comment: just curious :) may i know why to iterate backwards ?

Comment: If you don't, then you'll be mutating the array while iterating over it. Splicing out element 1 while iterating over element 1 means that the next index is 2 - what *used* to be in 2 is now 1, so it doesn't get iterated over.

Comment: ahh makes sense ... thanks :)